# many-to-many relationship on single table using code first with additional properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I am trying to create a code first model for my database where I have to create a many-to-many relationship on a single table with some additional properties. My classes are follows:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Owner { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public User User { get; set; }
    public User User1 { get; set; }
}
```

My User class is fairly simple for now but it looks something like this:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<Contact> Owner { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

That's how I tried to do it, but I get the exception whenever I try to access data from any model. The message of exception states that "Contact creates cycles in the database" and gives InvalidOperationException exception.

Please help me fix this problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `InversePropertyAttribute`, also fix the rest code:

```
public class Contact
{
    //other properties...

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Owner { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("User1")]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User User1 { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    //other properties...

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Owner { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("User1")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```